# How can I combine three subprocess.popen into one line?

Tags: python

I am currently using

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
count = int(p3.stdout.read())

if count == 2:
   print count
   print "yes"
else:
   print "fail"
```

For checking to see if my python is currently running already or not.
It works fine.

However, I want to know if I can combine `p1` `p2` and `p3` into one line.

I tried

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ps ax | grep bash | wc -l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and few more but its not working.Is there a way to combine all these 3 into one line?

Comment: You don't need the command string inside a list. Remove the brackets and all should be well.

Comment: @MattDMo He'd also need to add `shell=True` for it to work; that's the only way you can pass the full command as a string, and the only way you can use `|` as a pipe.

Comment: @dano good catch, I missed that.

Comment: @dano what do you mean by shell = true?

Comment: @Tim From the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) docs: *"If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~ to a user’s home directory"*.

Comment: You can trivially replace `grep | wc -l` (or the obvious `grep -c`) with simple Python code. Using the shell to do stuff Python is good at is just wasteful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use shell-style pipes (`|`) if you pass the `shell=True` keyword argument to `Popen`:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('ps ax | grep bash | wc -l', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

Otherwise, the entire string you pass is treated like the name of the executable, which will fail, since you don't have a program named `ps ax | grep bash | wc -l`.

Additionally, you shouldn't pass the command as a list with `shell=True`, you just pass a string.

One other note: You probably need to adjust your command for this to work reliably, so that the `grep bash` command itself isn't counted in the output of `ps ax | grep bash`. One trick to do this is to use `ps ax | grep [b]ash`. Also, using `shell=True` might end up starting a bash instance to run the command, so you might need to use `if count == 3` instead of `if count == 2`.

Putting it altogether:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('ps ax | grep [b]ash | wc -l', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

count = int(p.stdout.read())

if count == 2: # Or maybe 3?
   print count
   print "yes"
else:
   print "fail"
```

**Edit:**

Here's output from running different versions of the code on my machine

```
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.read()
'42\n'
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.read()
'42\n'
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.read()
'42\n'
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.read()
'42\n'
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p2 = subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], stdin=p1.stdout,    stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE); p3.stdout.read()
'42\n'
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep bash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
44

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep bash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
44

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep bash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
44

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep [b]ash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
42

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep [b]ash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
42

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('ps -ef | grep [b]ash | wc -l ', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True) ; print(''.join(p.stdout.readlines()))
42
```

Comment: One final note here: It's only safe to use `shell=True` if none of the command you're running is built using input from the user. You're not doing that here, so it's fine. But if any part of the command *was* from user input, it wouldn't be safe to use `shell=True`.

Comment: when I use my original coding, the count is 2... and I tried your program.. count is 4 not 2 or 3... can you explain why?

Comment: also why did you add [] on bash .? [b]ash?

Comment: @Tim The square brackets on `[b]ash` prevent the `ps ax | grep [b]ash` command from matching itself. If you run `ps -ef | grep bash` from the command prompt a bunch of times, at least some of those times you'll see `ps -ef | grep bash` show up in the output, which isn't really what you want. Using `grep [b]ash` will make grep match the string `"bash"`, but *not* the string `[b]ash`, so it will always exclude itself from the output.

Comment: @Tim Did you include the square brackets when you ran it? If I exclude them, I get a value two higher than I would have expected, but if I include them, the output matches the output of your original example. See my edit for output from my machine.

Comment: after I made some changes again.. your coding with [] returns 3 without it return 5 and my orignal coding returns 2.. i understand about the []with out part.. but can you explain why I get 3 for with []?

Comment: @Tim The easiest way to see what it is would be to run `ps ax | grep [b]ash` only, and look at the output. Then you'll see exactly what three programs are running that matched. My guess is that it's matching the shell Python is spawning to run your command, since that would only exist with `shell=True`.

Comment: I ran few times.. and it keeps on giving me different numbers.. either 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the obvious answer. All I did was replace the second p1 and p2 with the first assignment.

```
p3 = subprocess.Popen(['wc', '-l'], stdin=subprocess.Popen(['grep', 'bash'], \
     stdin=subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'ax'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout, \
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```